# All self-hosted agents cannot connect to devops site

Tags: azure-devops

All of our self-hosted agents cannot connect to DevOps this morning, they are failing with:

```
...
[2022-01-31 23:38:04Z ERR  VisualStudioServices] Attempt 4 of GET request to https://dev.azure.com/xxxxxxxxxx/_apis/connectionData?connectOptions=1&lastChangeId=123456789&lastChangeId64=123456789 failed (Socket Error: ConnectionReset). The maximum number of attempts has been reached.
[2022-01-31 23:38:04Z INFO VisualStudioServices] Finished operation Location.GetConnectionData
[2022-01-31 23:38:04Z INFO AgentServer] Catch exception during connect. 2 attempt left.
[2022-01-31 23:38:04Z ERR  AgentServer] System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Attempting to uninstall the agent gives me the same error. Attempting to install a new agent in a different folder gives me the same error.

1. Agent versions are 2.193 and 2.194
2. All servers are Win2012, and are hosted in our own non-Azure location
3. The URL in the error message can be accessed successfully from a browser on the server
4. executing `run.cmd --diagnostics` in the agent folder shows no errors/issues

Anything I'm missing to check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be caused by TLS1.2.

> Azure DevOps services will no longer accept connections coming over
> TLS 1.0 / TLS 1.1 and require TLS 1.2 at a minimum from January 31,
> 2022. This applies to all HTTPS connections to Azure DevOps Services including web API, and git connections to
> https://dev.azure.com/orgname and https://orgname.visualsdtudio.com/.

Please see [Deprecating weak cryptographic standards (TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1) in Azure DevOps](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/deprecating-weak-cryptographic-standards-tls-1-0-and-tls-1-1-in-azure-devops/) for details.

So, please make sure the machine is using TLS 1.2 protocol or higher. Check https://aka.ms/enableTlsv2 for more information on how to enable TLS in your machine.

You can refer to this document to enable TLS 1.2:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2